# "On Thursday" or "Thursdays"?

Tags: nouns, present-simple

When I refer to a habitual activity that takes place regularly once a week, do I need to use a plural form of the name of the day of the week or a singular one?

> I do one sport on **Thursday** at this time.

or

> I do one sport on **Thursdays** at this time.

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referring to doing sports weekly you can say:

"I do sports on Thursday this week" - implying that next week it may or may not be on the same day.

"This week I do sports on Thursday" - same meaning as above, and applies for a single activity.

It would be more formal and technically more correct to say:

"I do one sport on Thursdays" - this leaves it rather vague as to whether you do different sports each Thursday or the same one; but it is acceptable to do that, you are not obligated to be more specific.

Fencing, showjumping, shooting, swimming, running, archery, even fishing or hunting are sports. You do not "play swimming, archery, fishing or hunting, etc.".

Usually playing of sports involves playing with another person on your team but there are exceptions. You do not "play synchronized swimming". You do "play tennis" whether it's one on one or doubles.

> In what context could I possibly say "I do a kind of sport"?

I do swimming, skated and ice hockey on Thursday. - correct even though you "play hockey".

> So, you can't say "I do a sport" in English at all?

Incorrect.

Example:

Tom: "Joe, you complain about your weight but never do anything about it!".

Joe: "I do a sport".

Tom: "Which one?".

Joe: "I prefer not to say".

Comment: WOW! Very informative! Thank you! (your answer contradicts a bit to @Maulik V's answer, but for some reason, I trust yours more :)  )

Comment: @brilliant - Thank you. I also prefer my own answer but someone whom teaches English for a living and has far better qualifications may come along with a better answer, eventually. You are welcome to change your preferred answer but I think there are restrictions on changing it back again - so best to wait until it looks like you are not going to get any more answers and your question is down the list.

Comment: Okay, I'll wait.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you use plural because then you are referring to ***all*** Thursdays and not just one.

> I go to a temple on *Sundays*

Just an additional note: you don't *'do'* sport, you *play it* in this context.

Comment: Thank you. In what context could I possibly say "I do a kind of sport"?

Comment: Still.... I *play a kind of sport* that is adventurous.

Comment: So, you can't say "I do a sport" in English at all?

Comment: You can...but it'd be in contrast. Say - I am not on diet, but I *do* sport. However, I'm not *super sure* about this usage! ^-^

Comment: What about this:  "We don't work on Thursday".  The speaker means they don't work on any Thursday during the month. So, need pluralrity?